# Show: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f\geq k\right\})\leq\int f\, d\mu\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f>k\right\})$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Show that für $f\colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ measurable, it is
> >     $$
> > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f\geq k\right\})\leq\int f\, d\mu\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f>k\right\}).
> > $$

I do not know if one needs it here, but we defined the integral of a non-negative measurable function $f\colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\overline{\mathcal{B}})$ by
$$
\int_{\Omega}f\, d\mu=\sup\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\inf\left\{f(x): x\in A_k\right\})\mu(A_k): n\in\mathbb{N}, A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathcal{A}\mbox{ disjoint },\Omega=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right\}.
$$

---

My first idea was to use this definition, but I did not come along with it...

Maybe you can help me to show that?

(I think, maybe it has something to do with monotone convergence theorem or majorated convergence?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Show the pointwise identity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(\{f\geq k\})\mathbb{1}_{(k-1,k]}(t)\leq \mu(\{f\geq t\})\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(\{f\geq k-1\})\mathbb{1}_{(k-1,k]}(t),
$$
for $t> 0$. Then integrate all three terms with respect to $\lambda$ (being the Lebesgue-measure). You will have to use monotone convergence theorem as well as the fact that for non-negative functions $f$ one has
$$
\int_\Omega f\,\mathrm d\mu=\int_0^\infty \mu(\{f\geq t\})\,\lambda(\mathrm dt).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Funny, I have to prove the same statement!

I did it this way:

At first I show that it is pointwise
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}\stackrel{\mathrm{(*)}}\leq f\stackrel{\mathrm{(**)}}\leq\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}.
$$

Proof of $(*)$:

Consider any $\omega\in\Omega$.

**Case 1**: $0\leq f(\omega)<1$. Then $1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=0~\forall~k\geq 1$, i.e. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=0$ and therefore $f(\omega)\geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)$.

**Case 2**: $1\leq f(\omega)<\infty$, i.e. $f(\omega)=M$ with $1\leq M<\infty$. Then it is $1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=1$ for $1\leq k\leq\lfloor M\rfloor$ and therefore $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=\lfloor M\rfloor\leq M=f(\omega)$.

**Case 3**: $f(\omega)=\infty$. Then it is $1_{\left\{ f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=1~\forall~k\geq 1$, i.e. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}(\omega)=\infty=f(\omega)$.

The proof of $(**)$ is very similar, I leave it out here thefrefore.

Because of the monotony of the Lebesgue integral it is
$$
\int \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}\, d\mu\leq\int f\, d\mu\leq\int \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}\, d\mu.
$$

Now I defined the fundamental functions
$$
f_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}},~~g_n:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}
$$

which are non-negative and measurable. Moreover it is
$$
f_n\uparrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}},~~g_n\uparrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}.
$$

Using the theorem of monoton convergence and the definition of the Lebesgue integral for non-negative and measurable fundamental functions, it follows
$$
\int \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\sum_{k=1}^{n}1_{\left\{f\geq k\right\}}\, d\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(\left\{f\geq k\right\})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f\geq k\right\})
$$
resp.
$$
\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}\, d\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}1_{\left\{f>k\right\}}\, d\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\mu(\left\{f>k\right\})=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\mu(\left\{f>k\right\}).
$$

So that's it.

I am excited to hear your opinions to my proof.

Comment: Could anybody pls. say me if this proof is correct? To my opinion it is, but I am not totally sure.